# how to change to before and after constraints without pressing button and using uicolorview as a button (swift code)?

Tags: function, animation, button, swift2, constraints

The code listed below has a button that when is pressed makes the large blue box turn into a small blue box. How can the code be written so that I can just click on the blue box for it turn into the smaller box? The blue boxes are not images they are simply are coded using uicolorview. Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let colorview = UIView()
    var allc = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        colorview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        colorview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.view.addSubview((colorview))

        let leadingc = colorview.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingC = colorview.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor)
        let topc = colorview.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor)
        let bottomc = colorview.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leadingc, trailingC, topc, bottomc])

        let widthc = colorview.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
        let heightc = colorview.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100)
        let centerxc = colorview.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor)
        let centeryc = colorview.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor)

        allc = [leadingc, trailingC, topc, bottomc, widthc, heightc, centerxc, centeryc]
    }

    @IBAction func changethebleep(sender: AnyObject) {

        var newactive = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

        for constraint in allc {
            if constraint.active {
                constraint.active = false
            } else {
                newactive.append(constraint)
            }
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(newactive)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view.

Comment: where in the code would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. To set up, you should add following code to the end of `viewDidLoad()` firstly.

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
colorview.userInteractionEnabled = true
colorview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

and then and handler message `imageTapped(omg:AnyObject)` like:

```
 func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
    var newactive = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    for constraint in allc {
        if constraint.active {
            constraint.active = false
        } else {
            newactive.append(constraint)
        }
    }
}
```